# Powershell: Register-ObjectEvent io.filesystemwatcher - Can a single registration watch for created and renamed?

Tags: powershell

I have something like this snippet:

```
$Watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder_to_watch, $file_name_filter -Property @{ 
    IncludeSubdirectories = $false
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier $eventname -Action {
   $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
   $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
   $fileextension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($name) # extract extension as string from filename
   $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
```

Right now, this event only fires on file creation.

I want it to fire both on creation and rename.

I tried this:

```
Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher -EventName 'Created,Renamed'
```

But this does not work a syntax error is raised:

> "Register-ObjectEvent : Cannot register for the specified event. An
> event with the name 'Created,Renamed' does not exist.       Parameter
> name: eventName

Is that possible (and how is it done), or must I declare two events?

(It is not clear from the docs if this is possible, or how to do it in powershell)

**SOLUTION**

The answer below from HAL9256 is valid. However, before discovering that path, I modified the event type to "changed"

This catches file creation and file rename (and some other things). Since my action code filters to make sure only desired files are actually processed, the event type of "changed" meets my needs at this time.

Comment: This page seems informative. https://btcstech.com/powershell/filesystemwatcher-2/

Comment: @lit Thanks! It does not seem to answer my question, based on my review.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can only subscribe to one event at a time.

But you *can* have multiple subscribed events registered to the same Action. For ex. If you define your action in a [Script Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks), you can subscribe both `Created` and `Rename` to the same Action.

```
$Watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder_to_watch, $file_name_filter -Property @{ 
    IncludeSubdirectories = $false
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

#Your script block
$Action = {
   $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
   $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
   $fileextension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($name) # extract extension as string from filename
   $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
}

Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier $eventname -Action $Action
Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher -EventName Renamed -SourceIdentifier $eventname -Action $Action
```